# GraffitiCMS Comment Forms

Tags: macros, graffiticms

In GraffitiCMS v1.2, I'm trying to include the comment form on my blog posts, but the submit button does nothing. Comments are enabled for the post, and I've included $macros.CommentForm() in the blog.post.view file. I've also confirmed that the necessary Ajax.ashx file exists on the root. Are there any other dependencies?

Are there any instructions posted anywhere that explain how to make this work? I've been Googling for several hours and can't find any.

NOTE: I cannot upgrade to v1.3 at this time. Hopefully on a future project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was already doing as Jeremy H suggested, and calling `$macros.Head()`, but my use of jQuery was conflicting with Prototype. I resolved the problem by linking in jQuery *before* `$macros.Head()` and switching out all my jQuery $ tokens to use the actual jQuery function name.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the `/__utility/js/graffiti.js` and `/__utility/js/prototype.js` scripts linked on your page. Calling `$macros.Head()` should do this automatically.